# Order By not working with eager loading laravel (not sortBy)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I am facing an issue please if someone can help

I want to get sorted inventory by apply orderBy clause on eager loaded table column

blow is my code and you can check laravel doc for the reference
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

my code

```
$inventoryFilterQuery = Inventory::with(['inventoryPrice' => function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->orderBy('inventory_price', 'desc');
        }])->get();
```

but I am not getting sorted inventory and I want to achieve this by eloquent

Inventory and InventoryPrice have one to one relation.

Comment: Right now, `orderBy` is sorting only the inventoryPrice, not the inventory itself. The duplicate explains how to use Laravel's sortBy Collection method to sort the parent by the child attribute

Comment: @aynber you are right but sortBy is not a query builder function it can only apply on a collection I want to order by before getting the collection. because when you use sortby you cant manage pagination it will only sort current page data not from whole data.

Comment: Ah, pagination throws a whole other monkey wrench in it. You can still use the collection sort and paginate that, but depending on the size of the data, that might be cost-intensive. Your other option would be to use a mysql join, which can then sort the Inventory table.

Comment: yes exactly thats the issue I cannot use sort by and pagination at the same time first its the repetition of task and next it will just give me current page sorting. now please if you have any other solution except this mysql join and sorting thing please help